# Can I use Replace with Wildcard

Tags: sql-server

So, a `varchar` variable can have 'Y,N,X' or 'X,Y,N' or 'Y,X,N' or 'X'

I want to replace it X along ',' with empty string
for example
if @value = 'Y,N,X' OR   'X,Y,N' OR    'Y,X,N' OR   'X'
then Replace x with '' would look like this
=  'Y,N'  OR   'Y,N'  OR 'Y,N' or ''

| Input | 'Y,N,X' | 'X,Y,N' | 'Y,X,N' | 'X' |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Output | 'Y,N' | 'Y,N' | 'Y,N' | '' |

I don't want to use

```
 REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(@value,',x,',''),'x,',''),',x',''),'x','')
```

Is there any cleaner way to

Comment: If you have restricted the input to 4 choices, of which 3 map to the same output then just look for the 'X'. If it isn't X then assume it maps to 'Y, N'?

Comment: What is your reason for not wanting to use the 4 replace methods? You may be able to find other methods that work...but they won't necessarily be more efficient.

Comment: And other methods may also not be any easier to read. For example, I'm thinking of other ways to get the same result, but it still involves the same or more functions than in your example. Do you just not like how it looks?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From SQL Server 2017 (14.x) and later, you can use STRING_SPLIT and STRING_AGG to split/join string data

Run the test code below to check

```
DECLARE @value NVARCHAR(20) = 'X,Y,X,Z,X'
DECLARE @wildcard NVARCHAR(10) = 'X'
DECLARE @separator NVARCHAR(10) = ','

SELECT STRING_AGG(VALUE, @separator) as 'Result' 
FROM STRING_SPLIT (@value, @separator) 
WHERE VALUE <> @wildcard
```

Result

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I think this is the simplest SQL I can do because SQL Server does not support regular expression.

```sql
create table t (f nvarchar(50));
insert into t values ('Y,N,X'), ('X,Y,N'), ('Y,X,N'), ('X');

with t2 as 
(
--Make all item to have trailling comma, and delete item X
select replace(f + ',', 'X,', '') f2
from    t
)
--Remove right most item's comma except data without item
select case when f2 <> '' then left(f2, len(f2) - 1) else '' end f3
from   t2;
```

I am appending another answer after viewing Manh Nguyen's [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/65318434/2958717)

It is using `string_split` and `string_agg` function as he answered.

```sql
--Join with comma after excluding item 'X'
select string_agg(s.value, ',') f2
from   (
       --Generate row number to join after excluding item 'X'
       select row_number() over (order by (select 1)) rnum,
              f
       from t
       ) t
       cross apply string_split(t.f, ',') s
where  s.value <> 'X'
group by t.rnum
```

Using `string_split` and `string_agg` function is clear to understand.

But not simple because you need to generate unique row number for each item to gather correct item when using `string_agg` function.

Maybe you can choose different way for different circumstance.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure what exactly you need!

but I think you need to edit your SQL statement from :

```
REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(@value,',x,',''),'x,',''),',x',''),'x','')
```

to

```
REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(@value,',x,',','),'x,',''),',x',''),'x','')
```

> -- Replace ',x,' to ',' instead of empty string

for not ending up with value 'YN' instead of 'Y,N'